# UWP- MediaElement for Video

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player, uwp-xaml

I created media element player for video. But when it runs, only audio is playing but video is not showing. I am using Visual Studio 2015. thanks in advance

Comment: we will be happy to see some of your code

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your video format is not supported by the standard media element. You can try by using [VLC.MediaElement](https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement), it's a clone of the MediaElement but with VLC 3.0 as underlying media player.